# Work with dynamic Images in responsive web application

Tags: php, css, responsive-design

I am working on responsive web application. My designer used `370x700px` Images in static pages. It works perfectly with responsive with the css and js code for images including this `width:100% height:auto`.

In this site I am uploading product images from the admin panel.In without responsive website I was creating different size of thumbnails, but In this case I am worried that should I create thumbnail of size `370x700px`? These images are too big to load and i have to load 10 images on one page. minimum size of the image is 150kb. so `150*10 = 1500kb` only for images except other contents. These are the small images, big images resolution is around `700x1800px` which I will show on product detail page in zoom section.

Is there any other way to do it? should I create 370*700px thumbnail images from admin panel?

Comment: if these are on static html pages. then you can create the thumbnails and change the images via JS using jquery library.

Comment: another way is to load all the images as preload options

Answer (score 0):

Here is some old code I wrote that will resize any image from a DB.  It still uses the deprecated mysql_* but that is easy enough for you to update.

It is designed to take $GET arguments, img (the row on the db corresponding to the image), min,max,height,width.  Depending on which of those are set, it will either fix an absolute value or try to fit the image to a size you need.  This will allow you to upload one image only then resize that dynamically for your pages.

```
    $sql=sprintf("SELECT image,filetype,width,height FROM image WHERE imageline='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['img']));
$result=mysql_query($sql,$dbh);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$filetype=($row['filetype']!="")?$row['filetype']:"image/jpeg";
$content=base64_decode($row['image']);
$newheight=0;
$newwidth=0;
if($row['height']==0||$row['width']==0)
    {

    header("Content-type: $filetype");
    echo ($content);
    die;
    }

if($_GET['max']>0)
    {
    if($row['height']>=$row['width'])
        {
        $_GET['height']=($_GET['max']>$row['height'])?$row['height']:$_GET['max'];
        $_GET['width']=0;
        }
    if($row['width']>$row['height'])
        {
        $_GET['width']=($_GET['max']>$row['width'])?$row['width']:$_GET['max'];
        $_GET['height']=0;
        }
    }

if($_GET['min']>0)
    {
    if($row['height']<=$row['width'])
        {
        $_GET['height']=$_GET['min'];
        $_GET['width']=0;
        }
    if($row['width']<$row['height'])
        {
        $_GET['width']=$_GET['min'];
        $_GET['height']=0;
        }
    }

if($_GET['height']>0&&$_GET['width']==0)
    {
    $newheight=$_GET['height'];
    $newwidth=$row['width']*($_GET['height']/$row['height']);

    }
if($_GET['height']>0&&$_GET['width']>0)
    {
    $newheight=$_GET['height'];
    $newwidth=$_GET['width'];
    }
if($_GET['width']>0&&$_GET['height']==0)
    {
    $newwidth=$_GET['width'];
    $newheight=$row['height']*($_GET['width']/$row['width']);   
    }

if($newheight>0&&$newwidth>0)
    {
    $newheight=floor($newheight);
    $newwidth=floor($newwidth); 
    $image=imagecreatefromstring($content);
    $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($newimage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight,$row['width'], $row['height']);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($newimage);
    die;
    }
header("Content-type: $filetype");

echo ($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a php script that can resize the images in the fly and use it something like this

/image-resizer.php?source=path-to-the-image-here&width=x&height=x